# Reactjs dropdown list population from props data

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a dropdown select box but populate the list items in that dropdown box using some data I have passed to the componenent. I keep running into a "Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must not have `children` or use `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of AssignModal." error and I am not sure how to solve it. Here is the code I am using:

In this function I am trying to dynamically generate the drop down items

```
createUserDropdown: function() {
let items = [];

for (let i = 0; i < this.props.userData.user_data.length; i++) {
     items.push(<option key={this.props.userData.user_data[i].id} value={this.props.userData.user_data[i].id}>{this.props.userData.user_data[i].first_name}</option>);
}
 return items;
}
```

Here is my render function

```
render: function() {
return (
<div>
  <form className='form-inline' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="select" label="Multiple Select" multiple>
       {this.createUserDropdown()}
    </input>
  </form>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Can you just return an array like that and JSX will somehow unbox it from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select isn't a valid input type. Select actually has it's own tag with it's children being option. Just change `<input>` to `<select>`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select